# Simple way to resize large number of image files

Tags: shell, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a folder which contains about 45000 jpeg images. Most of them are from 10KB - 20Kb. 
Now I want to write a script to resize all of them to fixed size 256x256. I wonder if there is any simple way to do that like: `for a in *.jpg do ...`. I am using 8-core CPU with 8GB of RAM machine running Ubuntu 14.04, so it is fine if the process requires many resources

Comment: [Use imagemagick instead.](http://cubiq.org/create-fixed-size-thumbnails-with-imagemagick)

Comment: Cheers. Imagemagick is the answer to most "how do I do X to a lot of images?" questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use GNU Parallel, like this to make the most of all those cores:

```
find . -name \*.jpg | parallel -j 16 convert {} -resize 256x256 {}
```

If you had fewer files, you could do it like this, but the commandline would be too long for 45,000 files:

```
parallel -j 16 convert {} -resize 256x256 {} ::: *.jpg
```

Also, note that if you want the files to become EXACTLY 256x256 regardless of input dimensions and aspect ratio, you must add `!` after the `-resize` like this `-resize 256x256!`

As Tom says, make a backup first!

Here is a little benchmark...

```
# Create 1,000 files of noisy junk @1024x1024 pixels
seq 1 1000 | parallel convert -size 1024x1024 xc:gray +noise random {}.jpg

# Resize all 1,000 files using mogrify
time mogrify -resize 256x256 *.jpg

real    1m23.324s

 # Create all 1,000 input files afresh
seq 1 1000 | parallel convert -size 1024x1024 xc:gray +noise random {}.jpg

# Resize all 1,000 files using GNU Parallel
time parallel convert -resize 256x256 {} {} ::: *.jpg

real    0m22.541s
```

You can see that GNU Parallel is considerably faster for this example. To be fair though, it is also wasteful of resources though because a new process has to be created for each input file, whereas `mogrify` just uses one process that does all the files. If you knew that the files were named in a particular fashion, you may be able to optimise things better...

Finally, you may find `xargs` and `mogrify` in concert work well for you, like this:

```
time find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} -n 100 -P 8 mogrify -resize 256x256 {}

real    0m20.840s
```

which allows up to 8 `mogrify` processes to run in parallel (`-P 8`), and each one processes up to 100 input images (`-n 100`) thereby amortizing the cost of starting a process over a larger number of files.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `mogrify` tool provided by ImageMagick

```
mogrify -resize 256x256 *.jpg
```

This modifies all files in place, resizing them to 256x256px. Make sure to **take a backup** of your originals before using this command.